# Help in acm style

Tags: bibtex, natbib, acm

Hello I am using `acm` package for my bibliography.

In my report the reference numbers are being displayed in simple brackets i.e. `()`. However, i want them in square brackets i.e. `[]`. Also, multiple citations are separated by ";" not by ",".

Comment: Which command do you use to create multiple citations? Please consider posting a MWE that shows what you've tried so far.

Comment: for multiple citations i used    ~\cite{a,b,c}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've set the `natbib` tag, I'm inferring that you're using the `natbib` citation management package. If this inference is valid, you could load the package as follows to achieve your objectives:

```
\usepackage[square,semicolon]{natbib}
```